# Android AlarmManager

Tags: android

I have an Alarm Manager which send Intent to BroadcastReceiver. This Broadcast is not in Manifest. I register it onResume and unregister onPause in my Activity. What I need is to Save 2 boolean Preferences when app is not active and time of alarm is come. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it if you register in the activity.
You need to move to manifest and have a dedicated broadcast receiver class for it. This way even if the activity is not running you will still get the alarm.

In the BroadcastReceiver than you can write to Preferences.